# Update multiple rows throws The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I want to update all rows in table [listings] with a new friendlyurl value. Instead of looping through all records I thought I could also do it like so:

```
;WITH vars1 AS (
SELECT title FROM listings where listingtype=2 order by createdate desc)
UPDATE listings set friendlyurl=REPLACE(LOWER(vars1.title),' ','-')
```

But I get the error on the last line:

**The multi-part identifier vars1.title could not be bound.**

How can I correct the above statement to work as I intend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a CTE to update then you could use:

```
;with vars1 as
(
  select title, friendlyUrl
  from listings
  where listingtype=2 
) 
update vars1 
set friendlyurl = REPLACE(LOWER(vars1.title),' ','-');
```

But you can do this without a CTE:

```
update listings
set friendlyurl = REPLACE(LOWER(title),' ','-')
where listingtype=2;
```

See [Demo with both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2559a/1)

Comment: @nurdglaw [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) is similar to a derived table but can be self referenced